# How do I upload an image in ASP.NET Core WEB API with other form data?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi, webapi

I'm trying to make a form that will take necessary form data plus a profile picture and store it in a WEB API because I'm gonna consume this API later in MVC. I'm kind of confused on how I should configure my HttpPost.
This is my User class:

```
public partial class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Email { getl set; }
    public string ProfilePhoto { get; set; }
}
```

This is what my HttpPost looks like in my UsersController:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<User>> PostUser(User user)
{
    _context.User.Add(user);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return CreatedAtAction("GetUser", new { id = user.Id }, user);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I upload an image in ASP.NET Core WEB API with other form data?

The way you are trying it might work initially but still it’s not elegant even will bring additional hassle in future if you would like to upload multiple pictures against a single user. So you could try this way which mostly practiced.

**ViewModel:**

```cs
public class UserViewModel
        {
           
            public string FirstName { get; set; }

            public string LastName { get; set; }

            public string Email { get; set; }
           
            public List<IFormFile> profilePicture { get; set; }
        }
```

**Note:** As you can notice property from your `User Model` Are same we have introduced `profilePicture` List as `List<IFormFile>`.

**UserProfilePicture Model:**

```cs
public class UserProfilePicture
    {
        [Key]
        public int UserProfilePictureId { get; set; }
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public string ImageName { get; set; }
        public string ImagePath { get; set; }
    }
```

**Note:** This this the main `table/Class` which will deal all the pictures and files related stuff to the `users` class which make the `User Class` loosely coupled as per `SOLID principle` which stated

> **Single-Responsibility Principle** "A class should have one and only one reason to change, meaning that a class should have only one job"

> **Open-Closed Principle** "Objects or entities should be open for extension but closed for modification."

As you can see `UserId` has used as `foreignkey` reference. You can refer the related database table below:

[image]

**Note:** Always keep in mind while the project small and best practice followed in a long run it will be well maintained otherwise lot of issues may begin gradually.

**Controller:**

```cs
        [Route("CreateUserProfilePic")]
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> CreateUserProfilePic([FromForm] UserViewModel model)
        {

            if (model == null)
            {
                return Content("Invalid Submission!");
            }
            //Insert in User Model
            var userModel = new User
            {
                FirstName = model.FirstName,
                LastName = model.LastName,
                Email = model.Email,

            };
            _context.Add(userModel);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            var lastUserId = userModel.Id;
           
            foreach (var item in model.profilePicture)
            {
               
                if (item.FileName == null || item.FileName.Length == 0)
                {
                    return Content("File not selected");
                }
                var path = Path.Combine(_environment.WebRootPath, "Images/", item.FileName);

                using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    await item.CopyToAsync(stream);
                    stream.Close();
                }


                //Insert In User Profile table
                var userProfileModel = new UserProfilePicture
                {
                    UserId = lastUserId.ToString(),
                    ImageName = item.FileName,
                    ImagePath = path

                };
                _context.Add(userProfileModel);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
           
            return Ok(model);

        }
```

**Note:** You can split the `upload functionality` in a separate method. In addition, you picture should be saved in `wwwroot` folder and database should save it's referece as `path or image name`. As you can see below:

[image]

**And In database It would be kept as like below:**

[image]

**Output:**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can take 2 parameters. One for "User" and other for the "Image". The Image parameter should be `IFormFile` type.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<User>> PostUser(User user, [FromForm] IFormFile file)
{
    _context.User.Add(user);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    // save to image or do any of your work.

    return CreatedAtAction("GetUser", new { id = user.Id }, user);
}
```

Check [File Upload Web API Tutorial](https://www.yogihosting.com/aspnet-core-consume-api/#upload-files) where you will find all the details along with full codes.

Comment: If for example I need to upload two different images in my API, say a profile picture and a cover photo, does that mean that I should take in three parameters? Two of those being the IFormFile for the two images?

Comment: In that case you use `[FromForm] List<IFormFile> file` for parameter.

Comment: I see. How would I be able to reflect that on the database in a way that one is on the profile picture column or the cover photo column? Because I'm thinking that I should set my user model like this right?
`public partial class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Email { getl set; }
    public List<IFormFile> Files { get; set; }
}`

Comment: It is totally up to you how you set your model. Images path should be stored in the database, actual images should be saved inside "wwwroot/images" folder.